# issues running keycloak server on docker container in plesk

Tags: docker, wildfly, keycloak, plesk

So im trying to run a Keycloak server on my Plesk server in a docker container.

The issue is that my keycloak server dies after a while(or after an action, im not sure because nothing gets logged), all im getting in the log is

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions (jar:file:/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/extension/elytron/main/wildfly-elytron-integration-11.1.1.Final.jar!/) to method com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider.isFIPS()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
*** JBossAS process (340) received KILL signal ***
```

I have the required env setting `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` to true, and im pretty sure i followed the instructions properly on https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/10.0.2/server/README.md

I have tried with and without TLS settings and it still just dies after about 5 min

here is some extra log dump after setting it to extreme verbose logging

```
[0m16:51:30,688 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Attempting to find all resources META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.2.0.Beta1-db2.xml in Module "org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa" version 10.0.2 from local module loader @797cf65c (finder: local module finder @31bcf236 (roots: /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base))
[0m16:51:30,705 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Attempting to find all resources liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd in Module "org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa" version 10.0.2 from local module loader @797cf65c (finder: local module finder @31bcf236 (roots: /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base))
[0m16:51:30,770 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Attempting to find all resources META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.2.0.CR1.xml in Module "org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa" version 10.0.2 from local module loader @797cf65c (finder: local module finder @31bcf236 (roots: /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base))
[0m16:51:30,771 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Attempting to find all resources liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd in Module "org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa" version 10.0.2 from local module loader @797cf65c (finder: local module finder @31bcf236 (roots: /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base))
[0m16:51:30,882 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Attempting to find all resources META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.2.0.CR1-db2.xml in Module "org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa" version 10.0.2 from local module loader @797cf65c (finder: local module finder @31bcf236 (roots: /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base))
[0m16:51:30,904 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Attempting to find all resources liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd in Module "org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa" version 10.0.2 from local module loader @797cf65c (finder: local module finder @31bcf236 (roots: /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak,/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base))
[0m*** JBossAS process (148) received KILL signal ***
```

Edit: so def seems to have something to do with Java having an OOM crash

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bit late, as far as am concerned, this error happened to me while using `jboss/keycloak v14.0`.

Am using it with `Plesk and Docker proxy https://<hostname>/auth`.

It was working before (was using v13.0)

So, even `v13.1` gave me the same error.

Finally, I decided to switch back to jboss/keycloak v13.0.

/!\ - Be ready to loose your data, or map container volume with the host while testing.